# Javascript - Don't understand data type of a variable

Tags: javascript, casting

I have the following:

```
this.replaceBand1 = "1";
...
var replaceEndValue = Integer.valueOf(this.replaceBand1);
replaceBeginValue = replaceEndValue + 1;
//what is going on?
var type1 = typeOf replaceEndValue;
var type2 = typeOf replaceBeginValue;
log.debug("replaceEndValue: " + replaceEndValue + " " + type1);
log.debug("replaceBeginValue: " + replaceBeginValue + " " + type2);
...
setValue(column1, replaceEndValue);
setValue(column2, replaceBeginValue);
```

My expected outcome: replaceBeginValue will equal 2, and I can pass that into the function setValue that requires an Integer.

Actual outcome: replaceEndValue works, replaceBeginValue does not work.

The first debug shows - `replaceEndValue: 1 object`
The second debug shows - `replaceBeginValue 2 string`

I have no idea why replaceBeginValue is a string. Can anybody help?

Comment: This isn't standard JavaScript, what else are you using?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `JS`

Comment: It's JavaScript that gets dumped into Java, so the setValue and Integer.valueOf functions are Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need `parseInt` instead of `Integer.valueOf`. The function `parseInt` returns an `int` primitive type.

---

If you would like `replaceBeginValue` to equal 2, you would need something like this:

```
this.replaceBand1 = "1";
...
var replaceEndValue = parseInt(this.replaceBand1);
replaceBeginValue = replaceEndValue + 1;

...
```

Note: `Integer.valueOf` is for Java not JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, Frogatto. I used the parseInt to do the math in JavaScript, and then it turns out that value was being passed into Java as a double, so usage of Integer.valueOf on the answer to dump it into the Java function.

It works now.